# "Show in Local Terminal" in Eclipse keeps popping up a duplicate Terminal window outside of Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I select the "Show in Local Terminal" dropdown menu for a given project (or Ctrl+Alt+T) in Eclipse, it always pops up a duplicate Windows terminal window that duplicates everything I type in the internal Terminal window in Eclipse.
[image]

How can I disable this duplicate popup? I don't see any settings that control this behavior. I've used Eclipse (STS Spring Tool to be precise) for years, never had this issue. Recently installed STS on the new machine and can't get rid of this duplicate popup terminal.

Comment: "Local Terminal" might be specific to STS. The "Terminal" option, which is the only one I have mentioning terminals, opens the selected folder in the Terminal View.